# Manage SharePoint 2010 Navigate Up

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to manage "Navigate Up" navigation nodes either by code or any available UI.  My requirements are  simple as i want to hide "Navigation" from the below list as below:

**Current**

[image]

**To be**

[image]

Comment: this is already looks like to be custom created plz provide customization

Answer (score 0):

Is this your navigational index on the left end of the page? If so, you can hide it by going to site actions -> site settings and select "navigation" under look and feel and simply hide navigation and it should work fine or you can go to content and structure and edit the files there itself...hope this helps